# Toggling visibility of a link on Cloned Elements jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a div which uses a "duplicate" link to clone the div, then hides the FIRST "duplicate" link, leaving only the most recent link visible.

When I remove a cloned div, I can't seem to traverse the DOM correctly in order to show that first "duplicate" link again.

```
<div class="group">
<a class="remove">x</a> // hidden until div is cloned

<a class="add">Duplicate</a>
</div>
```

Cloning the div:

```
$("a.add").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".group").find("a.remove").show();
    $(this).closest(".group").clone(true).insertAfter($(this).closest(".group")).addClass("duplicated").find("a.remove").show();
    $(this).parent().find("a.add").toggle();
});
```

Removing a cloned div + adding the "Duplicate" link back in:

```
$(".remove").click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".group").remove();
});

$(".duplicated .remove").click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".group").find("a.add").show();
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agv8af0n/)

I've tried a million combinations of .prev(), .parent(), and .closest() but can't get any of them to work.

Comment: `$("a.add")` Where's the anchor with this class in your example?

Comment: @j08691 oops, edited to add the right anchor into the example code.

Answer (score 1):

Your below code is not working, because as your manipulating that dom, which is no longer exists. and there is no need to add/bind the click event when you are already having one.

```
  $(".duplicated .remove").click(function() {
        $(this).parent(".group").find("a.add").show();
    });
```

I change that function to get your requirement done.

```
$(".remove").click(function() {
    if($(this).parent().find('.add').is(':visible'))
        $(this).parent('.group').prev('.group').find("a.add").show();
  $(this).parent(".group").remove();  
});
```

This will only visible the 'duplicate' link for it's previous node, if duplicate link is visible for the current node.
Hope this will be helpful !.